# How to create UICollectionView cells with unique background images and UIButtons programmatically

Tags: uibutton, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a UICollectionView that uses the same background image for every cell (the cell size is the screen size). How can I set unique background images and buttons for each cell? Please see my code below:

**PageCell**

```
import UIKit

class PageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()

}

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.backgroundColor = .yellow
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "bg")
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.anchorToTop(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

**MenuViewController:**

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,   UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .red
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    return cv
}()


let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    //use autolayout instead
    collectionView.anchorToTop(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

    collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout     collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

extension UIView {

func anchorToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left:     NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

    anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
```

}

```
func anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left:     NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant).isActive = true
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an array with `yourUniqueImages`. Then set it in `cellForItemAt     indexPath`: `cell.imageView.image = yourUniqueImages[indexPath.row] `.

Comment: @shallowThought how do I access `imageView.image` since  in `cellForItemAt indexPath` `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath)`?
`

Comment: I do not understand. Simply put `cell.imageView.image = yourUniqueImages[indexPath.row]` below `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)`.

Comment: @shallowThought `cell.imageView.image = yourUniqueImages[indexPath.row]` gives a `Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member imageView` error

Comment: You have to cast it: `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PageCell`. You should go through a UICollectionView tutorial once.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks, it's working. I went through a tutorial but I guess I didn't understand the larger part of it :). Please, what about the buttons? I am making a game menu so some cells would have more buttons than others in different positions. How can I add the buttons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130498/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-ironthrone).